# Could someone explain this section about events in Xlib?

Tags: x11, xlib, xorg

The section I am confused about is from [*Volume One: Xlib Programming Manual*](https://www.niksula.hut.fi/~jkirma/books/xlib.pdf#page=36).

> Keyboard and pointer events are generated in the smallest window
>   enclosing the pointer (or grabbing the pointer, as discussed in
>   Section 8.3.2.2, "Keyboard and Pointer Grabbing").  Then an event of
>   one of these types (only) propagates upward through the window
>   hierarchy until the event type is found in the `event_mask` or
>   `do_not_propagate_mask` attributes of the window.  If the event is found
>   in an `event_mask` first (or in both on the same window), then the event
>   is sent as if it occurred in that window, and if it is found in a
>   `do_not_propagate_mask` first, then it is never sent.  The ID of the
>   window that finally received the event (if any) is put in the window
>   member of the event structure.

What does the author mean by "generated" in relation to keyboard and pointer events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All events are serialised as 32 bytes of data, "generated" in your context is "fill 32 bytes of data with all required information (some is common across events like target window id, event server time, some is specific to event type like x,y of pointer position or key code of key pressed )" + send it to a socket associated with connection

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html

> Events are 32 bytes long. Unused bytes within an event are not
>   guaranteed to be zero. Every event contains an 8-bit type code. The
>   most significant bit in this code is set if the event was generated
>   from a SendEvent request. Event codes 64 through 127 are reserved for
>   extensions, although the core protocol does not define a mechanism for
>   selecting interest in such events. Every core event (with the
>   exception of KeymapNotify) also contains the least significant 16 bits
>   of the sequence number of the last request issued by the client that
>   was (or is currently being) processed by the server.

Comment: So every time you move your mouse 32 bytes of data is sent to a socket and then Xserver draws the cursor based on that event?

Comment: Server knows which region on the screen need which cursor and updates cursor accordingly ( don't need communication with client for this ). 32 bytes are sent to a socket for each client that set corresponding event mask on a window under cursor. If no mask set - no data sent